# Android App Not Responding on Ionic Emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, emulation

Upon running the Ionic Android Emulator, my application appears as expected (although very zoomed in, a separate issue). However, when I try to click a button within the app, there is no response (for example, all that appears is the app's homepage and I cannot click anything to move on to sign-in page).

I've run a template ionic app on the same emulator and it works perfectly, so there must be something wrong with my app itself. However, when I run 'ionic serve' so that the app appears in my browser, all functionality is available.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to approach this issue? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

Fixed it! fixed it! i ran `ionic emulate android --livereload --consolelogs --serverlogs1`, which suggested that i run `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`, and it's been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case others come across this issue in the future:

Run:

```
ionic emulate android --livereload --consolelogs --serverlogs1
```

Which will prompt you to run:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```